# Javascript Error Tracking Tools

Tags: javascript, tracking

can anyone suggest any Javascript Error Tracking Tools that they have used.

We are using ExceptionHub but it doesn't quite work with knockoutJS in ie.
Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Google` best tool to find answer to your question.Try `firebug`

Comment: Nowadays, most of the browsers having very good debugging capabilities natively. But you need to learn it first before you can try your hand on it.

Comment: You can try https://www.atatus.com

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` is the best one for error tracking.We need to install firebug for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Firebug. Or Chrome Developer Tools - just hit F12 in Chrome to show the Developer Tools.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We are looking for a tool that sends emails every time an unexpected error happens on our production system. Obviously we try to have a bug free code but want to know of any unexpected javascript errors. Firebug is quite useful while developing not for reporting purposes. –

Answer (score 0):

You can give RootCause a try. They have a 30 day free trial

Disclaimer: I work for [RootCause](https://therootcause.io/feature-tour/). Our software automatically reproduces JavaScript errors and lets you replay user sessions live in your browser with the click of a button.